# Catch function flags change event in IDA plugin

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

Is there a way for plugin to understand that function flags were changed (e.g. through function-edit menu, by setting 'library' or 'static' flag)? There is idb_event::func_noret_changed, but seems it doesn't issued. Nevertheless, I can't find any event which issued when other flags change in SDK. Is it impossible?

Comment: I don't think there's a formally-defined way to do what you're asking, but hooking calls to `areacb_t_update()` may allow you to catch function flag changes.